# Tidyverse: Error in as.matrix : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I am trying to calculate SPEI values using `SPEI` package and `Hargreaves` method. I want to automate the process so that I can calculate SPEI for all 6 stations in one go and save them to a new file `spei.3`.

SPEI is calculated in three steps. First, we calculate PET values (`spei_pet`), which is then subtracted from Precipitation value to calculate climatic water balance (`spei_cwbal`). The CWBAL value is then used in `SPEI` function from the package of the same name with a `scale` to calculate SPEI values.

I am new to R and very new to `tidyverse`, but the internet says they are easier to work on. I wrote the code below to do my task. But I am surely missing something (or maybe, many things) because the code throws an error. Please help me identify error in my code, and help me get a solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(SPEI)

file_path = "I:/Proj/Excel sheets - climate/SPI/heatmap/spei_forecast_data.xlsx"
file_forecast = openxlsx::read.xlsx(file_path)

##spei calculation

spei.scale = c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 24)
stations = c(1:3, 5:7)
lat = c(23.29, 23.08, 22.95, 22.62, 22.43, 22.40)

lat.fn = function(i) {
  if (i <= 3)
    lat.fn = lat[i]
  else if (i == 5)
    lat.fn = lat[4]
  else if (i == 6)
    lat.fn = lat[5]
  else if (i == 7)
    lat.fn = lat[6]
}

for ( i in stations) {

  file_forecast %>% 
    mutate(spei_pet[i] <- hargreaves(Tmin = file_forecast$paste("tmin", i),
                                    Tmax = file_forecast$paste("tmax", i),
                                    Pre = file_forecast$paste("p", i),
                                    lat = lat.fn[i])) %>% 
    mutate(spei_cwbal[i] <- spei_pet[[i]] - file_forecast$paste("p", i)) %>% 
    mutate(spei.3[i] <- spei(spei_cwbal[[i]], scale = 3))

}
```

It throws an error

```
Error in as.matrix(Tmin) : attempt to apply non-function
```

`lat.fn[i]` also throws an error, which gets rectified if I use no `i`. But I need to use some kind of function so that lat.fn takes different value depending on `i`.

```
Error in lat.fn[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Thanks.

Edit: The data is in the form of a data.frame. I converted it into a tibble to give an idea of what it looks like.

```
> file_forecast
# A tibble: 960 x 20
   Month     p7     p6     p5     p3     p2     p1 tmax7 tmax6 tmax5 tmax3 tmax2 tmax1 tmin7 tmin6 tmin5 tmin3 tmin2 tmin1
   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Jan    0.162  0.185  0.293  0.436  0.529  0.658  26.4  26.5  26.2  25.9  25.7  24.9  9.57  9.75  10.0  10.4  9.94  9.77
 2 Feb    0.207  0.305  0.250  0.260  0.240  0.186  32.2  32.2  32.1  31.9  31.8  30.9 12.4  12.7   12.7  13.0 12.2  11.9 
 3 Mar    0.511  0.650  0.602  0.636  0.625  0.501  37.3  37.1  37.1  37.0  36.9  36.1 18.7  19.3   18.3  18.0 17.3  16.9 
 4 Apr    0.976  1.12   1.05   1.12   1.17   1.16   39.5  39.2  39.6  39.5  39.5  38.8 22.8  23.2   22.5  22.2 21.7  20.8 
 5 May    3.86   4.12   3.76   4.29   4.15   3.84   38.2  37.9  38.3  38.1  38.2  37.6 25.1  25.4   24.9  24.7 24.5  23.8 
 6 Jun    7.31   8.27   7.20   8.51   9.14   8.76   38.0  37.6  38.1  38.0  38.0  37.7 27.2  27.3   26.9  26.7 26.6  26.1 
 7 Jul   13.9   15.6   13.2   17.0   19.1   17.8    33.9  33.6  34.0  33.9  33.8  33.5 26.8  26.9   26.6  26.5 26.4  26.0 
 8 Aug   15.2   17.2   14.4   18.6   20.1   18.4    32.6  32.4  32.7  32.4  32.3  32.0 26.2  26.4   26.1  25.9 25.9  25.4 
 9 Sep   11.4   11.9   10.5   12.9   13.2   13.1    31.9  31.9  31.8  31.5  31.5  30.9 24.4  24.6   24.3  24.3 24.3  23.7 
10 Oct    5.19   5.76   4.81   5.40   5.44   5.04   29.8  30.0  29.6  29.3  29.3  28.6 20.9  21.1   20.8  20.9 20.8  20.2 
# ... with 950 more rows, and 1 more variable: year <dbl>
```

Comment: You defined `lat.fn` as a function. You call a function with `lat.fn(i)`, not `lat.fn[i]` -- use parenthesis to call a function.

Comment: That seems to have solved error related to lat.fn. But the `Error in as.matrix(Tmin) : attempt to apply non-function` still persists. Please help me resolve that too. Thanks.